# Cache static images permanently asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache, clientcache

I want all my static images to get cached on browser (on first request) and fetched from browser cache for further request to the page.

I tried adding `<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Fri, 23 Dec 2016 00:00:00 GMT" />` to my Web.config, but it still does a request to the server and gets 304 as return.

What i am trying is to permanently cache static images on client side, so that it doesn't request to server and images are fetched from the browser cache.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `manifest` attribute if `HTML 5` in any web development environment. What you have to do is create manifest file, give images (or any static content) path there and use that file as a value of `manifest` attribute. [More Info](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this using Web.confg..?